# IRremote sending only works once with Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, atmega328, remote-control, infrared

I am trying to control a receiver, wich is not working. I believe i have to send the code at least three times... but after the first time the IR Led stays off. I am using the Arduino Nano with the LED connected to pin 13. The "Send" message keep printing.

- I am using this lib: https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote
- I tried multiple versions of the lib

My code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

const static unsigned int raw[68] = {8950,4450,550,550,600,550,600,500,600,550,550,550,600,500,600,550,600,500,600,1600,600,1600,600,1650,550,1650,550,550,600,1600,600,1600,600,1650,550,550,600,1600,600,1600,600,550,550,550,600,500,600,550,550,550,600,1600,600,550,550,550,600,1600,600,1600,600,1600,600,1600,600,1650,550};

void loop() {  
  Serial.println("Send");
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    irsend.sendRaw(raw,68,38);
    delay(40);
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

- Works only again once when resetting the Arduino

Comment: In all the examples found in the project's github files the delay between transmissions is over an order of magnitude longer than 40ms. Maybe that would help.

Comment: `I believe i have to send the code at least three times`  ... then what is preventing you from repeating `irsend.sendRaw(raw,68,38)` two more times?

Comment: @st2000 40ms is about right for the NEC protocol. The RAW code looks a lot like NEC.

Comment: Are you saying you can't see the IR led light up three times in a row, or that it isn't repeating after the 5 second delay? The former is pretty unlikely for you to notice, as the led being off for 40ms is hard to notice for us humans.

Comment: Got it to work... Code is fine. Pin 13 was the problem, because for the Nano it actually is Pin 3.  I actually tested it earlier with another LED but my other one was for some reason really dark, so i  just missed it.